# What pascal compilers can target embedded ARM with no OS?

Tags: embedded, arm, pascal

Looks like available Pascal compilers can only produce binaries for ARM on Linux. Is there established version of compiler/bundle for just bare ARM cpu with zero extra software preinstalled ?

To clarify, I am looking for high quality, compact tool (alternative to commercial C, open source C) for kernel-less, plain embedded CPU with all software in one plain ROM ? IDE with debugging capabilities is nice to have, but not necessary. Dubugger could actually be some different 3rd party generic IDE. I hope that compilers can dump the debug/symbols info in some standard form.

Thank you

Comment: The full featured ness of the runtime library may be more of an issue than the absence of a kernel.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning RTL. I now starting to recall what was involved to build Turbo Pascal 7.0 RTL from ASM/TASM from scratch. There was a tiny binary piece needed still, even with all source opened as ASM.

Comment: I think it is more a matter that FPC doesn't spoon feed you something like that (due to the plethora of devices and options), not that it isn't possible. Afaik people have run code on LPC devices without linux. The entire FPC source is in FPC with small bits in GAS assembler. No binary blobs. What a commercial bit as TP did is irrelevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Free Pascal Compiler supports ARM without any OS. They call it **[TARGET EMBEDDED](http://wiki.freepascal.org/TARGET_Embedded)**.

For ARM Linux take a look at **[this](http://www.mme-berlin.de/arm9-modul/index.htm)** and **[this](http://www.turbocontrol.com/easyfpgui.htm)**.

There is also **[Lazarus CT edition](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&catid=68&Itemid=147)** cross compiler which seams to target sysless ARM too.

UPDATE 1: mikroElektronika has also recently made **[Pascal compiler for ARM](http://www.mikroe.com/eng/products/view/754/mikropascal-pro-for-arm)**.

UPDATE 2: [**Ultibo framework**](https://ultibo.org) for bare metal Raspberry Pi programming looks outstanding.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like Free Pascal is the only option

Comment: Even Pascal stronghold Embarcadero (which current owns Delphi) currently distributes Free Pascal as ARM option

Comment: Sadly, your second "this" link and your link to Lazarus CR edition are both broken